# check whether it is uniformly continious or not?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $$F= \{f:R→ R:  |f(x)-f(y)| ≤ K|(x-y)|^a \}\forall x , y ∈ R$$  and for some $a > 0$ and some  $K>0$.
which of the following are true ?

1. Every differentiable function f is in F,
2. every f ∈ F is differentiable .
3. every f ∈ F is uniformly continious .

my attempt ; as i take $f(x) = x^2$ as we know that it is not uniformly continious on $R$ but it is differentiable .
so my answer is option 1 and option 2 are correct  ..

is my answer is correct or not ...pliz tell me the solution

Comment: please use Mathjax for your posts.

Comment: $x^2$ does not satisfy the condition that $|x^2- y^2|\le K|x- y|^a$ so that a irrelevant.

Comment: a >0 given so i take a= 2@ user247327

Answer (score 0):

1) is not true, as your example $f(x)=x^2$ shows. Then $f$ is differentiable but does not belongt to $F$.

2) is not true, as $f(x)=|x|$ shows. Then $f\in F$ (with $a=K=1$), but $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

3) is true. Pick $f\in F$ and $a,K>0$ so that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq K|x-y|^a$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$. For a given $\varepsilon>0$ choose $\delta=(\varepsilon/K)^{1/a}$. Then $|x-y|<\delta$ implies
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(y)|\leq K|x-y|^a<K\delta^a=\varepsilon.
\end{align}

Comment: thanks  a lots @srantthrop,,,2 and 3 i understand,,,but for 1) . how x^2 doesn't belong to F;;

Comment: Hint: To see that $f(x)=x^2$ does not belong to $F$, consider $\sup_{x\neq y}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|^a}$. Can this supremum be finite for some $a>0$?

Comment: still not getting ,,,that  for a= 1 we have x^2-y^2/x-y = x+y <  ε.....@sranthrop

Comment: $x+y\to\infty$ as $x,y\to\infty$. Note that $|f(x)-f(y)|/|x-y|^a\leq K$ has to hold for ALL $x,y\in\mathbb R,x\neq y$.

Comment: okkk,, thanks a lots ,,@sranthrop i will vote up ur answer now..

Comment: you're welcome. Don't hesitate to ask again, if there are any further questions.